# babelHelpers polymer throwing error after upgrade of babel

Tags: babeljs, polymer-2.x

After I did bower update and npm polymer-cli update.. I started getting this error in production. The error is coming from babelHelpers. It seems it stopped

> Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a
>   function, not undefined
>       at Object.r.inherits (:formatted:111)
>       at my-entry.html:1
>       at my-entry.html:1

This is line 111.

```
r.inherits = function(e, r) {
                    if ("function" != typeof r && null !== r)
                        throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof r);
                    e.prototype = Object.create(r && r.prototype, {
                        constructor: {
                            value: e,
                            enumerable: !1,
                            writable: !0,
                            configurable: !0
                        }
                    }),
                    r && (Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(e, r) : e.__proto__ = r)
                }
```

Here is the polymer.json

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/my-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    "src/my-entry.html",
    "src/my-login.html",
    "src/my-app.html",
    "src/my-view404.html"
  ],
  "sources": [
    "src/**/*",
    "images/**/*",
    "bower.json"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js"
  ],
  "lint": {
    "rules": ["polymer-2"]
  },
  "js": {
  "minify": true,
  "ignore": [
    "*.min.js",
    "firebase-database.js"
  ]
},
  "builds": [
    {
      "preset": "es5-bundled"
    },
    {
      "preset": "es6-bundled"
    },
    {
      "preset": "es6-unbundled"
    }
  ]
}
```

The structure of the app is something like this
Entry Point: index.html
Goes to src/my-entry.html
then it uses firebase auth state, if user is not logged in then it goes to a simple my-login.html. If user is logged in then it goes to my-app.html

Before upgrades, everything was working fine.

If I remove my-entry.html and directly go to my-app.html, then there doesnt show any error.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is in your my-entry.html? you probably missed calling a super function?

Comment: @daKmoR - I think you are right.. my shell was my-app and I was index.html was going to entry where I was lazy-loading my-app while showing my-login. I changed shell to my-entry and stopped lazy loading of my-app